# How to use different kinds of navbar components on different pages

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have two different navbar components created for two different subsystems of our project.

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<CirclePage />} />
          <Route
            path = "*"
            element={
              <>
                <Navbar/>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/homepage" element={<Homepage />} />
                  <Route path="/events" element={<Events />} />
                  <Route path="/clubs" element={<Clubs />} />
                  <Route path="/notifications" element={<Notifications />} />
                  <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
                  <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact/>}/>
                </Routes>
              </>
            }
          />

          <Route 
            path = "*"
            element={
              <>
                <NavbarClub/>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/homepage-club" element={<HomepageClubs />} />
                  <Route path="/events-club" element={<EventManagement />} />
                  <Route path="/contact-clubs" element={<ContactClubs />} />
                  <Route path="/notifications-club" element={<NotificationsClub />} />
                  <Route path="/profile-club" element={<ClubProfile />} />
              </Routes>
              </>
            } 
            />

        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar is visible on every screen except the main screen CirclePage. I want Navbar to be visible on homepage, events, clubs, notifications, profile and contact while NavbarClub to be visible in with the -club pages. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Create layout wrapper components for each that renders the specific navbar and an `Outlet` for nested `Route` components.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavbarLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const NavbarClubLayout = () => (
  <>
    <NavbarClub />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

App

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<CirclePage />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NavbarLayout />}>
          <Route path="homepage" element={<Homepage />} />
          <Route path="events" element={<Events />} />
          <Route path="clubs" element={<Clubs />} />
          <Route path="notifications" element={<Notifications />} />
          <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
          <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="*" element={<NavbarClubLayout />}>
          <Route path="homepage-club" element={<HomepageClubs />} />
          <Route path="events-club" element={<EventManagement />} />
          <Route path="contact-clubs" element={<ContactClubs />} />
          <Route path="notifications-club" element={<NotificationsClub />} />
          <Route path="profile-club" element={<ClubProfile />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-use-different-kinds-of-navbar-components-on-different-pages]

Comment: Both the code snippets on both of my questions are true but I sadly don't really understand what is going on. I am learning react at the same time implementing the project because this is a classwork and I don't know these concepts seem so weird to me. Can you explain me what happens especially with * and <route> inside <route>

Comment: @sarpoc Sure. `"*"` is a wildcard that can match any route. `react-router-dom` v6 can use relative routing/linking, so we're able to nest routes into each layout so `"/"` of "/homepage" is matched for the layout wrapper, *then* the rest is matched by the nested route. [Relative Routes and Links](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#relative-routes-and-links) from the v5 upgrade guide may help illustrate/explain better than I just did.